# How can I add domain to file when trying to change picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload and change image with jQuery. The upload  works fine and the response in ajax seems as expected. In console I got grfx/adam from variable result but in the img-tag I get error 404 not found and it looks like it added domain or something. The src looks like `http://localhost:8080/HM/%EF%BB%BF%20grfx/adam.jpg` and the result is a broken img-icon. The Javascript function look like this:

```
<script>
 
function uploadprofilepic() {
    $('#formupload').hide();
    $('#formcrop').show();



// Making the image file object
    var file = $('#newprofilepic').prop("files")[0];

    // Making the form object
    var form = new FormData();

    // Adding the image to the form
    form.append("image", file);
 // Adding the image to the form
    form.append("image", file);

    // The AJAX call
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadprofilepicture.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  form,
        contentType: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(result){
       // byter bild lokalt i hållare
       console.log(result);

       $('#picholder').attr("src", result);
        }
        });

}
</script>
```

what could possible be wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: What the URL in the browser when this page is open?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your server-side processing, which you've not included.

Comment: The server-script works as expected and The respons from my ajax call is grfx/adam.jpg  but The img src  get the domain added 
It is The same variable as you  can see for  console and img-attribut but different outputs

Comment: url in browser is: http://localhost:8080/HM/index.php?p=profile_settings

Answer (score 0):

Look like your code is correct but curious about the url `http://localhost:8080` is it backend Or front end. If this is frontend URL then you need to check where this image located and set the proper domain URL

I hope you are clear with this.